# ERROR: repetitive record violates the singular constraint "user_otherinfo_user_id_key"

Tags: django

> ERROR: repetitive record violates the singular constraint "user_otherinfo_user_id_key" DETAIL: The key "(user_id) = (52)" already exists.

After the user has added the update process, I get such an error during the registration.

`views.py`

```py
    def register(request):

        form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None )
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
            location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
            profile_image = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
            user.set_password(password)

            user.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)


         OtherInfo.objects.create(user=new_user,phone=phone,location=location,
         profile_image=profile_image)

            login(request,new_user)
            messages.info(request,"Successfully Register...")

            return redirect("/")
         context = {
                "form" : form
            }
         return render(request,"user/register.html",context)
```

`models.py`

```py
    class OtherInfo(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,verbose_name="Phone Number")
        location = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Location")
        profile_image = models.FileField(blank = True,null = True,verbose_name="Image")
```

`forms.py`

```py
    class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField()
        password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola',widget=forms.PasswordInput())
        password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola Again', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
        phone_number = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=11, label='Phone Number')
        location = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50, label='Location')
        profile_image = forms.FileField(required=False, label="Image")

        class Meta:
            model = User

            fields = [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'username',
                'password1',
                'password2',
                'phone_number',
                'location',
                'profile_image',
            ]
```

In Django, the user can register before updating the profile. When I add the profile update code, now the user is failing to register.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: please show traceback

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERROR: repetitive record violates the singular constraint "user_otherinfo_user_id_key"
DETAIL: The key "(user_id) = (69)" already exists.

Comment: Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: What does the `authenticate` method do?

Comment: The OtherInfo model is referenced from the User main model. It is used for user authentication when recording.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback means your user already has an OtherInfo.

You can use a ManyToOne(ForeignKey) instead of a OneToOne to allow a single User have mutiple OtherInfos. Or you have to add some kind of validation to check if your User already has an OtherInfo.

[This part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/) might help